# Update if row exists or insert if not based on user_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

A user can edit their location via an edit form on my site.

Some users may not have entered a location to begin with so I need the query to create a row and insert the user's user_id and username along with the location data they are submitting.

I'm struggling with after trying REPLACE INTO and multiple INSERT queries, obviously I'm not getting it right.

My Code;

```
    require("includes/common.php");

    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    {  
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    } 

$uid=$_SESSION['user']['id'];

$location_city = $_POST['location_city'];
$loctaion_county = $_POST['location_county'];
$loctaion_country = $_POST['location_country'];

// query
$sql = "UPDATE locations
        SET  location_county=?, location_city=?, location_country=?
        WHERE user_id=$uid";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($location_county,$location_city,$location_country));
header("location: edit-account.php");
```

Please note that I have I tried passing the username and user_id via pre-populated hidden fields into the database table and had other POST variables in the code above to insert that data.

The code above is working as it should for simple updates where I have manually created a user record in the locations table, for test purposes, by replacing the value in location_city.

UPDATE: Two options to proceed exist, not closed to any - 1) entries are created in tables at signup therefore negating the need to insert a row if it doesn't exist when editing a location. 2) a new row is created if it doesn't exist.

My signup code

```
<?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("includes/common.php"); 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. 
            die("Please enter a username."); 
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die("Please enter a password."); 
        } 

        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
        } 

        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this. 
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This username is already in use"); 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 

        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This email address is already registered"); 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table.
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email 
            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read. 
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk). 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Any errors? Turn on error reporting...

Comment: Would it not be possible to create a record at account creation in the location table but leave it blank if the user does not input something there. When you need to update it, you simply update rather try to insert.

Comment: An empty row would be useless until someone submits location data. Inserting a new row would be the preferred method.

Comment: Look at [`INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @Naruto No errors other than it not updating anything because the user's ID cannot be matched up to a corresponding with location_city.

Comment: @scottevans93 An empty row isn't useless as it creates a row with an auto incremented id, the user_id and their username for future use.

Comment: Or do a SELECT and check row count to see is row already exists, If not INSERT else UPDATE

Comment: @SGR I'm struggling to implement that approach in my registration script but yes that would have been my preferred method.

Comment: The reason i say it is useless, is due to the fact it holds no data, therefore just wasting memory.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the DUPLICATE KEY was something that I tried to do before trying REPLACE INTO. Both I failed at.

Comment: @scottevans93 ah I see, and take the point, but it is the only way I know how to do it and have the option for the user to add the data.

Comment: Can you please clarify you question a bit more, your aim seems slightly promiscuous as do you want to create the row on registration and update? Or do you want to insert a new row when someone comes to input location data?

Comment: `$password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt);` Use `password_hash()`, dont roll your own hashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issues I was having with `REPLACE INTO`, final code below for reference;

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$location_city = $_POST['location_city'];
$loctaion_county = $_POST['location_county'];
$loctaion_country = $_POST['location_country'];

    // query
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO locations(user_id,username,location_city,location_county,location_country) VALUES('$_POST[user_id]','$_POST[username]',$location_city,'$location_county','$location_country')";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($_POST[user_id],$_POST[username],$location_city,$locaion_county,$location_country));
    header("location: edit-account.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to insert a new row it should be like so;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO locations
    SET location_county=?, location_city=?, location_country=?, user_id=?
```

Of course this query would only be executed if a user is submitting location data for the first time. It would also be advisable to check if a row exists with the user's id & username before inserting a new row.

Comment: Even in PDO? I'm only after inserting if the update cannot match up a user_id

Comment: Well your logic choice is up to you. There are a number of approaches